# Latency while using Dropbox batch endpoint

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

We are trying to migrate file uploading to the batch endpoint (`/2/files/upload_session/start`) with the purpose to avoid namespace locking for the whole file uploading time. However we are facing a latency issue while finishing the batch. For example:

1. Starting a single file uploading. Call `/2/files/upload_session/start` with the file content (2MB) takes 1 second.
2. Finishing the batch. Call `/2/files/upload_session/finish_batch` with the session details takes 200 ms.
3. Verifying the batch completeness 1st time. Call `/2/files/upload_session/finish_batch/check` with the job id takes 200 ms, the tag in the response equals "**in_progress**".
4. Waiting 100 ms before checking again.
5. Verifying the batch completeness 2nd time. Call `/2/files/upload_session/finish_batch/check` with the job id takes 200 ms, the tag in the response still equals "**in_progress**".
6. Waiting 100 ms before checking again.
7. Verifying the batch completeness 3rd time. Call `/2/files/upload_session/finish_batch/check` with the job id takes 200 ms, the tag in the response finally equals "**complete**".

Why does the batch finishing (steps 2-7) take so much time?

P.S. no other uploads are performed at the same time during this test.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of things that will contribute to how long each of these API calls will take:

- the overhead of making the HTTPS calls themselves
- the network transit time
- the processing time on the Dropbox API server backend
- how many files are being committed

Unfortunately, these are out of the control the app, so there isn't much you can do to improve this. [The data ingress guide](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/data-ingress-guide) is worth reading though, if you haven't already. We'll also consider this a feature request for improving the performance, but I can't make any promises as to if/when that would be done.